# panel's location changing while making it visible on runtime at the checked changed event of a radio button. C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm adding a little code snippet of radio button click event. If this could help.

```
if (rbtnYesForPCPDetails.Checked){
    pnlUploadOnSharePointContainer.Visible = true;
    //grpBxPCPdetailsRequireChange.Visible = true;
    //grpBxFEtchFilesFromNGA.Visible = true;
    grpBxPCPCreationDecision.Visible = false;
    grpBxSurveyissued.Visible = false;
    grpBxSurveyReturns.Visible = false;
    grpBxEstimateProductionPT1.Visible = false;
    grpBxEstimateProductionPT2.Visible = false;
    }
```

The two commented groupboxes are already visible and the panel "pnlUploadOnSharePointContainer" show come below groupBox "grpBxPCPdetailsRequireChange" whereas what is happening is the panel is coming above "grpBxFEtchFilesFromNGA".

So, the actual visibility should be :

```
1. grpBxFEtchFilesFromNGA
2. grpBxPCPdetailsRequireChange
3. pnlUploadOnSharePointContainer
```

But what I'm getting is :

```
3. pnlUploadOnSharePointContainer
1. grpBxFEtchFilesFromNGA

2. grpBxPCPdetailsRequireChange
```

I have added the numbering to specify the flow.

Comment: "I have tried almost everthing" - post some of that code here so we can take a look. Winforms? WPF?

Comment: It would be useful to see your code for your radio buttons and for making the panels visible. If you're putting your application together in the designer, screenshots would probably be useful too.

Comment: @Equalsk It is a Windows form Project and It is C#

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is still really unclear. Why would the controls re-arrange themselves unless you made them? Are they in any kind of container that would do this like a FlowLayoutPanel?

Comment: That is what i'm wondering as there is no FlowLayoutPanel And a simple visibility change(true/false) .. It should not change its position altogether.

Comment: One more thing is it possible to change location of a panel at runtime ?

Answer (score -1):

I am getting your problem.

if you had use display property then change it from

```
display:block;
```

to

```
display:table-row;
```

It will resolve your issue.

Comment: Actually questionnaire even doesn't know about it whether it is css issue or code issue. But I have faced this issue several time.